# Sending multipart form data with Sttp library

Tags: scala, httprequest, multipartform-data

Within the frontend, I'm attempting to send a user-filled form to the backend (REST API) using [Sttp](https://github.com/softwaremill/sttp) (a Scala Http client). The form can include uploaded files so I'm using **Multipart Requests** as per the [documentation](https://sttp.softwaremill.com/en/latest/requests/multipart.html?highlight=multipart). Here's a sample:

**Library**

```
"com.softwaremill.sttp.client3" %%% "core" % "3.3.15",
"com.softwaremill.sttp.client3" %%% "circe" % "3.3.15"
```

**Model**

```
case class RateAResort(
                        id: String,
                        groupType: String,
                        review: String,
                        score_sf: Option[String] = None,
                        score_pa: Option[String] = None,
                        img1: Option[dom.File] = None,
                        img2: Option[dom.File] = None,
                        img3: Option[dom.File] = None
                      )
```

**Functionailty**

```
private def postRateAResortRequest(query: String, rar: RateAResort): Future[String] = {
    implicit val sttpBackend = FetchBackend()
    for {
      isAuthenticated <- AuthorizationManager.auth0Client.isAuthenticated().toFuture
      token <- if(isAuthenticated) AuthorizationManager.auth0Client.getTokenSilently().toFuture else Future("unauthenticated")
      response <- basicRequest
        .post(uri"$query")
        .multipartBody(multiPartPrepare(rar))
        .auth.bearer(token)
        .send(sttpBackend)
        .flatMap(Utils.failFutureOnStringError)
    } yield {
      sttpBackend.close()
      response
    }
  }

  private def multiPartPrepare(rar: RateAResort): List[Part[BasicRequestBody]] = {
    List(
      multipart("id", rar.id),
      multipart("groupType", rar.groupType),
      multipart("review", rar.review)
    ) ++
      rar.score_sf.fold(List[Part[BasicRequestBody]]())(o => List(multipart("score_sf", o))) ++
      rar.score_pa.fold(List[Part[BasicRequestBody]]())(o => List(multipart("score_pa", o))) ++
      rar.img1.fold(List[Part[BasicRequestBody]]())(o => List(multipartFile("img1", o))) ++
      rar.img2.fold(List[Part[BasicRequestBody]]())(o => List(multipartFile("img2", o))) ++
      rar.img3.fold(List[Part[BasicRequestBody]]())(o => List(multipartFile("img3", o)))
  }
```

However nothing is received on the backend (as handled by `Utils.failFutureOnStringError`). And I can see that the values from `rar` do output so I'm sure that this is the offending function (within the Sttp library):

```
def multipartBody[R2](ps: Seq[Part[RequestBody[R2]]]): RequestT[U, T, R with R2] = copy(body = MultipartBody(ps))
```

Briefly, the *function signature* for the function that the `POST` data gets sent to in the backend is `def saveRating: Action[MultipartFormData[Files.TemporaryFile]]` - which I have tested successfully in *Postman*.

Comment: Guess not then..